# How to configure Passenger for meteor app on local network

Tags: nginx, meteor, passenger

I am running into problems while deploying a Meteor app on my LAN with Phusion Passenger.
The app is running on an Ubuntu 16.04 server.

The config for the app in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ubuntu64;

    # Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
    root /var/www/appname/bundle/public;

    # Turn on Passenger
    passenger_enabled on;

    # Tell Passenger that your app is a Meteor app
    passenger_app_type node;
    passenger_startup_file main.js;

    # Tell your app where MongoDB is
    passenger_env_var MONGO_URL mongodb://user:pwd@localhost:27017/appname;

    # Tell your app what its root URL is
    passenger_env_var ROOT_URL http://ubuntu64;
}
```

The app runs fine and I can use the app from other PC's in the network, but only if I type the exact server IP address in the browser's address bar; not if I type the servername ("ubuntu64"). If I do that, I get a welcome page from Ngnix and the message that "Further configuration is required".

How should I change the config so that I can open the app with the servername, or rather with "servername/appname" because I am planning to host multiple meteor apps on the same server.

Edit: some more info from the logfile `/var/log/ngnix/access.log`:

I see this when connecting to "192.168.178.52":

```
192.168.178.77 - - [27/Sep/2017:13:43:58 +0200] "GET /sockjs/info?cb=oj4gdaujfh HTTP/1.1" 200 89 "http://192.168.178.52/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"
```

...and this is when connecting to "ubuntu64":

```
2001:983:e6ab:1:10d3:c8ad:4f1e:23f - - [27/Sep/2017:13:49:40 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"
```

BTW, I see now that the first line has a ipV4 address and the second line a ipV6. Could this be (part of) the problem?

Comment: How other PCs in the network know about this `ubuntu64` address? Do they have it added to their `/etc/hosts` or are they using your local DNS server where this address is resolving to your server PC?

Comment: They are using the DNS server on my (FritzBox) router.

Comment: And this `ubuntu64` is resolving to the same IP address your `nginx` listen on, correct?

Comment: `kantoor:~ willem$ ping ubuntu64

PING ubuntu64.fritz.box (192.168.178.52): 56 data bytes

64 bytes from 192.168.178.52: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.276 ms`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your edit has clarified your issue. You should allow your virtual host to listen on IPv6 as well.

It's quite easy:

```
server {
  listen [::]:80 ipv6only=off; # added line
  server_name ubuntu64;

  # the rest of your config
}
```

Useful information: [`ngx_http_core_module : listen` documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen).

**Added**: make sure your system allows `IPv6` sockets to work in `IPv4+IPv6` mode:

```
$ sysctl net.ipv6.bindv6only
net.ipv6.bindv6only = 0
```

Comment: After applying this edit, now both addresses give me the Nginx welcome screen with "Further configuration is required"...

Comment: connecting to 192.168.178.52 leads to: `192.168.178.77 - - [27/Sep/2017:14:27:25 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"` and connecting to "ubuntu64" gives `2001:983:e6ab:1:10d3:c8ad:4f1e:23f - - [27/Sep/2017:14:28:02 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"`

Comment: See my previous comment. Or do you need more logs? (there are no errors in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`)

Comment: I just completely rebooted the server and now the address "ubuntu64" is working ok. Typing the exact ip-address no longer works, but that is not a problem I think...

Comment: @willemx try to add `ipv6only=off` to the added line, like this: `listen [::]:80 ipv6only=off;`, that should fix not working on IPv4 address (I've edited my answer as well).

Comment: this edit leads to an error and nginx failing to start. In `/var/log/nginx/error.log` there are now error messages: `2017/09/27 15:02:25 [emerg] 2494#2494: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)`

Comment: @willemx The `ipv6only` option should be used just _once_ with the same address/port configuration. Just choose one of your server configuration and add it there, this option will be shared with all others `listen` directives on the same address/port.